# symfony2 - individual field validation yml callback

Tags: validation, symfony, callback, yaml

I'm a newbie to symfony 2.3 development. I'm working on a project which deals with form validation in yml file.
I want to put a callback on a single field but not on complete entity. Please give me any suggestion to work with this.

```
Acme\BlogBundle\Entity\Author:
constraints:
    - Callback:
        methods:   [isAuthorValid]
```

the above callback is working on all fields. How to call it for a specific field ?

Answer (score 0):

Read the [custom validation cookbook](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/validation/custom_constraint.html) article

```
Acme\BlogBundle\Entity\Author:
properties:
       name:
           - AppBundle\Validator\Constraints\isAuthorValid: ~
```

And then you create your custom Validators classes in Validator\Constraints directory following the Cookbook article.

Comment: hi @Martin, thanks for your kind reply. :)
I implemented it by following that article, but How can i get other form field values in the validate method except the current field value ?

Comment: I always did an independant validator class for each value. But if you need to do a validation of more fields, maybe there is a way to pass this extra value to the Validator Class.  Research. But I would keep it as simple as possible, there is really a need to validate 2 fields at the same time together ? Or you can achieve the same using independant field validation ?